# Replace FTP with SFTP to transfer files - PSFTP.EXE ONLY

Tags: ftp, putty, batch-file, file-transfer, sftp

I am currently `FTP'ing` file to a unix box from a `windows` server. I want to change the following section of the script and migrate the ftp process to be `sftp`.

```
@echo off
echo user %user%> ftpcmd.dat
echo %password%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %filetobeuploaded% %filepath%%File%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat %host%
del ftpcmd.dat
:END
```

I have `PSFTP.EXE` installed on my windows directory. Using that can I send the files with SFTP ?

How can I replace line `ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat %host%` to be SFTP. I understand you can do something like this....

```
CALL PSFTP.EXE someUserName@54.54.54.54 ....
```

If anybody is familiar, please can you help me complete it. what arguments would I give. user, pw, remotedir, host details are kept in a properties file. Im looking to use keys instead of password. Can you pass the existing ftpcmd.dat arg to psftp?

Comment: Please note, SFTP is NOT FTP + SSL. That is called FTPS. SFTP is a SSH based protocol, so you can upload to an SSH server with it, but not an FTP server. if you want to upload to an FTP server look into FTPS. see here for some info on the differences: http://superuser.com/questions/677966/ftps-versus-sftp-versus-scp/677971#677971

Comment: I guess what Im trying to ask above is how I maintain most of the written script above for ftp and make a small change to send it as sftp by using psftp.exe.

Comment: Have you tried `psftp -l %user% -pw %password% -b sftpcmd.dat %host%` where "sftpcmd.dat" contains `put %filetobeuploaded% %filepath%%FILE%` on one line and `quit` on another?  The biggest difference here seems to be that as is usually the case with ssh-oriented clients, the username must be specified when the command is called, rather than supplied after the fact as with traditional FTP.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use WinSCP. It supports both the SFTP and scripting.

See the [guide for converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP SFTP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

The script will look like:

```
open sftp://%user%:%password%@%host%
put -transfer=binary %filetobeuploaded% %filepath%%File%
exit
```

You can run the script like (if saved to `script.txt`):

```
winscp.com /script=script.txt
```

Note that (contrary to the `ftp.exe`), environment variables are resolved in WinSCP script too.

If you want to use a private key file, use:

```
open sftp://%user%@%host% -privatekey=path\key.ppk
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*